# Including the spotbugs target in build xml (ant)

Tags: java, ant, build.xml, spotbugs

excuse me, i struggle again. So the taskdef works fine, but i'm unable to actually work with spotbugs.

```
<target name="bugs" depends="compile">

    <spotbugs home="${spotbugs.home}"
        output="${spotbugs.output}"
        outputFile="bugs.${spotbugs.output}"
        excludeFilter="${spotbugs.exclude}">
    <sourcePath path="."/>
    <auxClassPath path="."/>
    <fileset dir="." includes="${package}/*.class"/>
</spotbugs>
```

So I want to check the code with

**ant -Dpackage=einstieg bugs**

and receive "Problem: failed to create task or type spotbugs". The same pattern I use for checkstyle works perfectly. The taskdefinition points to spotbugs and the needed class - without any error. Any suggestions?

So I think that the point to spotbugs simply doesn't exist. But there exists the suitable file in the /lib directory.

This is how the Taskdefinition looks like:

```
<!-- spotbugs settings -->
    <property name="spotbugs.home" value="C:/ant/lib"/>
    <property name="spotbugs.output" value="xml"/>
    <property name="spotbugs.exclude"
              value="C:/Users/wolfbiker/Documents/einstieg/exclude_filter.xml"/>
    <taskdef resource="edu/umd/cs/findbugs/anttask/tasks.properties"
             classpath="${spotbugs.home}/spotbugs-ant.jar"/>
```

Comment: Most developers use maven or gradle nowadays, are you pinned to ant?

Comment: Do you have read and followed: https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ant.html

Comment: hey, yeah so my professor wants us to use all ant tasks. already read the manual but maybe some more times to understand everything.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think when reading [Using the SpotBugs Ant task](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ant.html) in detail you will see that your

```
<property name="spotbugs.home" value="C:/ant/lib"/>
```

should not point into the ant home where you copied the **spotbugs-ant.jar**, instead it should point to a spotbugs installation itself - which is not the same as the spotbugs ant-task.
So spotbugs must also be installed beside the ant-task.

This also means that you have to change your classpath

```
<taskdef resource="edu/umd/cs/findbugs/anttask/tasks.properties" classpath="${spotbugs.home}/spotbugs-ant.jar"/>
```

to point to the spotbugs-ant.jar that you should have been copied to your ant/lib directory.

Comment: Hey thank your very much for your help. I actually didn't installed the SpotBugs Files to a seperate directory. I fixed this and also edited the build.xml file. Maybe there are still some mistakes because I still get the same error message. Sleep about it, maybe again some obviously mistake :X